# Convert satellite bands datatype to unit8 and then export to drive?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I am trying to export composite and classified bands from my GEE workspace to Drive.
This classification was performed on Sentinel-2 (COPERNICUS/S2_SR) image collection. The Datatype of bands all shows a different datatype. While [B1-B12] show 'unit64', my classified layer shows 'unit32'. As I want this data to be used to train on a Neural Network, I wanted to know, if it is possible to convert the data types of each band to unit8 and then export it to drive?

I am only interested in 'B2,B3,B4' and 'classification' bands.
This is the Bands info for 'im'(variable created to save the info)

```
Image (13 bands)
type: Image
bands: List (13 elements)
0: "B1", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
1: "B2", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
2: "B3", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
3: "B4", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
4: "B5", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
5: "B6", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
6: "B7", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
7: "B8", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
8: "B8A", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
9: "B9", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
10: "B11", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
11: "B12", double ∈ [0, 65535], EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
12: "classification", signed int32, EPSG:4326, 2x2 px
```

As per the [Developer Site](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-touint8) I modified the code as below:

```
var im8 = im.Image.toUnit8();
```

And got this error

```
Line 146: Cannot read property 'toUnit8' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things actually, you have a typo but you also called the method in a wrong way. No problemo though!

The API you linked is for an Image object which you already have with the name `im`. So the method is available directly for that object.

And the method is called `toUint8` (for Unsigned INTeger 8-bit), not `toUnit8`.

The correct call is:

```
var im8 = im.toUint8();
```